# React typescript useParams() always returns undefined in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-typescript

I am trying to achieve my profile component fetching logged user's data on path /me and fetching someone else's data on path user/:username.

Following example from react router blogs, I came up with something like this:

```
function App(): JSX.Element {

//...
            <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/me"
                render={(props) => (
                    <ProfileComponent {...props} principal={states.username} isMyProfile={true} />
                )}
            />
            <PrivateRoute
                path="/user/:username"
                render={(props) => (
                    <ProfileComponent {...props} principal={states.username} isMyProfile={false} />
                )}
            />
// ...
}


interface ParamTypes {
    path: string;
}

export default function ProfileComponent
  (props: { principal: string; isMyProfile: boolean }): JSX.Element {

  const { path } = useParams<ParamTypes>();

  useEffect(() => {
        async function fetch(username: string) {
            // ...
        }

        props.isMyProfile ? fetch(props.principal) : fetch(path);

    }, [props.principal, path, props.isMyProfile]); 

   // ...
}
```

but the path is always undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: you dont do it like this if the path is eg: path/create/:username(say) then it should be:
const {username}=useParams;
there is nothing like path in your case .

Comment: @Sakshi yup thats what I was missing and what bugged me for the past hours, if you add this as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Comment: done.you can check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you:

```
const { username } = useParams();

useEffect(()=>{
console.log(username)}
,[username]);
```

in case it's your profile then userName should be undefined otherwise you will get some value